# Accessing mobile browser location data in Django

Tags: django

I want to access location data from my users' mobile devices, are there any packages that simplify this? If not, any direction I should start looking into to identify how to do this myself?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Getting browser geolocation is totally a client side stuff, Django is irrelevant in this case.

You need to get user's geolocation in browser via javascript(), and send it to the Django web server. This a [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation) from *Mozilla Developer Network* about using the geolocation API.

However after getting the geodata, [GeoDjango](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/tutorial/) can help you store and query the geodata easily.

GeoDjango is a official contrib module for Django that turns Django into a world-class geographic Web framework.

Comment: That's what i was trying to get at without knowing it. Getting and storing. Thank you.